# Mirror bevel profile type

Tags: bevel

How can I Set the profile type to be mirrored along an axis for a vertex bevel? Or should I use a mirror modifier?

[image]

Comment: Can you tell us what this is for? The custom bevel profile isn't always the easiest tool to use..

Comment: it was for an arch, but the miter shape didn't have the shape i wanted, note that the curve i use was for making a point, not the intended shape i wanted to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to a mirrored custom bevel..

Non-destructive work on modified curves has always been a bit of a problem in Blender, because constructive modifiers convert curves to meshes.

I wonder whether this kind of workflow might work for you. First of all, in GN, it converts  whatever geometry you give it, to curves:

[image]

.. and then sweeps the modified geometry with a provided object:

[image]

.. which means, whatever objects are used for path and profile can be under modifiers themselves, (including a *Mirror*) before being used:

[image]

.. as the path (above), or the profile, (below):

[image]

[image]

Comment: wow thanks for the detailed explanation