# Geometry nodes: How to check object type

Tags: geometry-nodes

Hi Geometry Nodes friends.

Is there a way to check the object type in geometry nodes?

For example: I would like to check an object if it's a curve or a mesh and do things then.

I've an edges path and would like to convert it to a curve, but if it's already a curve I would like to do other things within the same geometry nodes tree.

Important: Of course, I know how to convert an edge to a curve etc. But I would like to know how to check the object type before doing something.

Is that possible?

Best wishes
Chris

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the separate components node is probably what you are looking for. By using it, you can split the objects of your scene depending on their type

[image]

Comment: Much better :)..

Answer (score 6):

In a [recent answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/304554/35559), I used this hack to check geometry type, by checking for the existence of the `curve_type` named attribute:

[image]

In that case, taking the sum over the geometry, to drive a *Switch*. To be honest, I'm not very comfortable with it.

Comment: Interesting. Did it work with the other types, too?

Comment: Not by itself, I don't think.. you could cascade tests? But the whole thing is  bit janky.. like OO downcasting.

Comment: @ChristophWerner Well, what does "work with the other types" mean? Other types like cameras, lights, empties? What would be working then? Those objects have no geometry, they are not meshes and cannot be converted to meshes, and therefore cannot be converted into curves... so the output would always be empty, no matter if there is a switch or not. Like in my slightly simpler answer, of course you can plug in other object types, but they will not produce any output because they cannot.

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann Basically you're right. But there're arguments for having this. If I want to do something with an edge or a curve, and a get a same result, it makes sense to check for the type. Example: You create a gn fence. The user can be free in creating a curve object or a edges mesh. In this case you need just one tree to create a fence.

Comment: @ChristophWerner I'm not questioning checking for edges or curves - that's what my answer is for, too... but you said "working with the **other types**"... what other types do you mean? Edges are meshes as well, so checking if it is a curve or a mesh works for edges, too. That's no different type, that's why I was asking if you mean cameras, empties etc.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann et al. Points, Instances?  I feel that testing for type ought to be a little alarm-bell that there might be a design problem. But Blender kind of introduces that by silently converting curves to their sampled mesh approximations for various operations.. (As far as I can see, the maths to maintain the curve definition would often be even more gnarled up )

Comment: @RobinBetts I hear that alarm-bell, too... anyway, instances wouldn't be a problem - you could always plug a _Realize Instances_ before the whole _Mesh to Curve_ and _Switch_ part, because (contrary to the _Mesh to Curve_ node which has an empty output if plug other than a mesh into it) a _Realize Instances_ node lets geometry that's not an instance simply pass through. For other things like points etc. you'd probably have to create more switches to detect all types and react to them... but as you said, that would be a design problem. Why make a nodetree like: throw all in to get a curve out?

Comment: @Gordon OK. Sorry for the misunderstanding... "German guy has problems understanding English, sometimes..." ;) Maybe I'm thinking to complex. You're right. Every other type, than a curve or a mesh would make no sence and ended in no results, what would be ok in this case.

Comment: @ChristophWerner Kein Problem, bin auch ein "German guy". Dann schau einfach welche Antwort dir besser gefällt.

Answer (score 6):

The way you could do it is with a *Curve Length* node and a *Math* node set to *Compare* if *Greater Than* 0. Of course this method has a flaw, if you plug in a curve with a length of 0, but I assume you do not use such an object. But the comparison is not necessary, depending on what you want to do next.

Because the practical setup depends on what "doing something" with the curve means. If you just want to make sure something is a curve to avoid having no output from the *Mesh to Curve* node, you can do it with a *Switch* node that uses the *Curve Length* for the *Selection*: a mesh will produce a *False* result, a curve will be interpreted as *True* if *Curve Length* > 0, so only the *False* branch needs the *Mesh to Curve* conversion:

[image: mesh to curve switch]